# How to test Drupal distributions and see examples

Tags: distributions, testing

Is there a way to see Drupal distributions already installed for testing as demo sites? I was searching drupal.org, where I only found 'case studies'. Sites there are sorted only by categories, not by used distributions, so it is difficult to check every site to find it out.

I want to use and feel distributions before installing them. It would be perfect if link to the demo site would be included in distribution description.

Answer (score 2):

Distributions and modules can easily be installed and tested at [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me)

Comment: I saw this, but is there a place where we can see gallery of websites which are already built and running using particular distribution?

Comment: Some distributions (as I'm sure you know) feature example sites on their project page, but other than that I'm not familiar with an index of sites built on various distributions.  Some distributions are fairly narrowly-focused (such as Commons) and for those distributions I can see how a set of example sites is useful.  Other distributions, however, like Panopoly, are very broadly-focused and provide a jumping-off-point to build almost any kind of site.  For those, examples might be almost as useless as examples of sites built with PHP.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so I would ask is there a library of demo sites, which use those 'narrowly-focused' distributions? I can't even see a link to the demo sites on commons project page..

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of anything like this.

Comment: Maybe I would create it then!

Comment: That's the spirit! :)